# Searching for certain services before changing a password

Tags: powershell, service

I would like to change all passwords for where the name contains "syn". I know you can do it by status which is what I am doing, but is there anyway to do it by searching the string's name?

```
$acctname = "domain\user"
$svcpwd  = "password"
#Text file
$servers = (gc serverlist.txt) 
#from AD 
#Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *)

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
  #Query service
  gwmi win32_service -computername $server | % { 
  if ($_.StartName -eq $acctname)
  {
    $servicename = $_.Name
    write-host "updating $servicename"
    $svcnm = gwmi win32_service -computername $server -filter "name='$servicename'"
    #Update Service
    $svcnm.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"$UserName",$svcpwd,$null,$null,$null) 
    #Stop Service
    $svcnm.stopservice
    #Start Service
    $svcnm.startservice
  }
}
```

Comment: So when yo usay where name contains "syn" do you mean the name of the service?

Comment: correct I just want to get a service or all services where it has syn in the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all services that start with a specific name you can add `$_.Name -like '*syn*'` to the if check like so

```
if (($_.StartName -eq $acctname) -and ($_.Name -like '*syn*'))
```

The new if statement will only trigger if the service you're looking for has a StartName equal to `$acctname` and a Name that has 'syn' in it, here's what your full code might look like

```
$acctname = "domain\user"
$svcpwd  = "password"
#Text file
$servers = (gc serverlist.txt) 
#from AD 
#Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *)

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
  #Query service
  gwmi win32_service -computername $server | % { 
  if (($_.StartName -eq $acctname) -and ($_.Name -like '*syn*'))
  {
    $servicename = $_.Name
    write-host "updating $servicename"
    $svcnm = gwmi win32_service -computername $server -filter "name='$servicename'"
    #Update Service
    $svcnm.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"$UserName",$svcpwd,$null,$null,$null) 
    #Stop Service
    $svcnm.stopservice
    #Start Service
    $svcnm.startservice
  }
}
```